# Why append a coreData entity into an Array set to nil relationship?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I trying to append an fetched entity from CoreData named `Timeline` (who's a message post) who contain a `Tree` and an `User` relationship.

All's good when i try to fetching it from CoreData, an user and a tree exist and there are not set to `nil`. But when i add it to my array, user relationship disappear but tree not, only the last `Timeline` entity in array keep the reference with both.

Here my loop on json, i fetch `Timeline` from CoreData by id or create it if CoreData don't know him inside `Timeline.get(withJSON:_, inManagedObjectContext:_)` :

```
var timelines = [Timeline]()
for jsonRow in json.arrayValue {
    if let timeline = Timeline.get(withJSON: jsonRow, inManagedObjectContext: context) {

        print("Timeline entitie from core data :\n", timeline)
        timelines.append(timeline)
    }
}

print("timelines array:\n", timelines)
```

Result of my print inside loop :

```
Timeline entitie from core data :
 <myApp.Timeline: 0x6080002a1560> (entity: Timeline; id: 0xd0000000046c0006 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/Timeline/p283> ; data: {
    createdAt = "2016-12-03 17:25:21 +0000";
    id = 21;
    message = "blablabla";
    tree = "0x60800023fa20 <x-coredata:///Tree/t742495B8-E258-4C42-8E69-AC9776194B7A22>";
    updatedAt = "2016-12-03 17:25:21 +0000";
    url = nil;
    user = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/User/p2>";
}) 


Timeline entitie from core data :
 <myApp.Timeline: 0x6000000bc620> (entity: Timeline; id: 0xd0000000047c0006 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/Timeline/p287> ; data: {
    createdAt = "2016-12-04 12:17:23 +0000";
    id = 22;
    message = "jaw dawd awdkj alwkjd alwkjd lawkjd lakwjd lakwjdl kawjl dkajwldkja wlkdjawl kjdawlk jdawlkjaw lkjawlkawjlkw aj lkawjd lkawjd lkjawdl kjawd awdl kajwldk jawlkjd lakwj dlakwj ldkajw lkdjawlk jlakwjd la";
    tree = "0x6000002354c0 <x-coredata:///Tree/t742495B8-E258-4C42-8E69-AC9776194B7A23>";
    updatedAt = "2016-12-04 12:17:23 +0000";
    url = nil;
    user = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/User/p2>";
})

Timeline entitie from core data :
 <myApp.Timeline: 0x6080002a1b60> (entity: Timeline; id: 0xd000000004800006 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/Timeline/p288> ; data: {
    createdAt = "2016-12-04 15:19:02 +0000";
    id = 30;
    message = "Niche";
    tree = "0x6080004279e0 <x-coredata:///Tree/t742495B8-E258-4C42-8E69-AC9776194B7A31>";
    updatedAt = "2016-12-04 15:19:02 +0000";
    url = nil;
    user = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/User/p2>";
})
```

And here the result of my array :

```
timelines array:
 [<myApp.Timeline: 0x6080002a1560> (entity: Timeline; id: 0xd0000000046c0006 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/Timeline/p283> ; data: {
    createdAt = "2016-12-03 17:25:21 +0000";
    id = 21;
    message = "blablabla";
    tree = "0x60800023fa20 <x-coredata:///Tree/t742495B8-E258-4C42-8E69-AC9776194B7A22>";
    updatedAt = "2016-12-03 17:25:21 +0000";
    url = nil;
    user = nil;
}), <myApp.Timeline: 0x6000000bc620> (entity: Timeline; id: 0xd0000000047c0006 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/Timeline/p287> ; data: {
    createdAt = "2016-12-04 12:17:23 +0000";
    id = 22;
    message = "jaw dawd awdkj alwkjd alwkjd lawkjd lakwjd lakwjdl kawjl dkajwldkja wlkdjawl kjdawlk jdawlkjaw lkjawlkawjlkw aj lkawjd lkawjd lkjawdl kjawd awdl kajwldk jawlkjd lakwj dlakwj ldkajw lkdjawlk jlakwjd la";
    tree = "0x6000002354c0 <x-coredata:///Tree/t742495B8-E258-4C42-8E69-AC9776194B7A23>";
    updatedAt = "2016-12-04 12:17:23 +0000";
    url = nil;
    user = nil;
}), <myApp.Timeline: 0x6080002a1b60> (entity: Timeline; id: 0xd000000004800006 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/Timeline/p288> ; data: {
    createdAt = "2016-12-04 15:19:02 +0000";
    id = 30;
    message = "Niche";
    tree = "0x6080004279e0 <x-coredata:///Tree/t742495B8-E258-4C42-8E69-AC9776194B7A31>";
    updatedAt = "2016-12-04 15:19:02 +0000";
    url = nil;
    user = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://D5FDDD6B-2A13-4B03-B592-45C99D801439/User/p2>";
})]
```

Thanks if you've got the answer, six lines of code never made me so crazy...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the relationship between `Timeline` and `User` is one to one. In the loop, you're giving each `Timeline` the same `User`. They look OK when you do that. But since the relationship is one-to-one, every time you assign that `User` to a new `Timeline`, you also nil out the previous value of the relationship. Each `User` can have only one `Timeline`, so when you assign the `User` to a new `Timeline`, the old one gets a nil value for the relationship. That's why it's the last one that has a non-nil value, because it's the only one that doesn't get changed by the next pass through the loop.

What to do depends on how your app works.

- If each `User` should only have one `Timeline`, fix your loop to assign a different `User` each time.
- If each `User` may have more than one `Timeline`, fix the relationship to be a to-many from `User` to `Timeline`.

Comment: No, really, `User` have a One-to-many relationships with `Timelines`. `Timeline` is an NSSet inside `User` and Timeline have an `User` propriety. This is the first thing that i've checked...

Comment: That's very strange, because your results are a perfect example of what would happen if the relationship were to-one instead of to-many.

Comment: Do you think that can be the difference between my `User` entity based on Coredata Xcode 8 model and `Timeline` in Coredata XCode 7.3 ?

Comment: I don't understand. Surely you're using both entities at the same time, not different entities depending on what version of Xcode you have?

Comment: Coredata has change version for Xcode 8 during my developement. I had to generate Timeline entity on CoreData of Xcode 7.3 and User on CoreData of Xcode 8.0. And i saw the possibility to choose what tool version minimum i wanted in xcdatamodeld file options. I wanted to know if it can generate errored entities. Thanks for your help and patience !